# Django makemigrations fail in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, migrate, makemigrations

I'm trying to deploy a Django (1.10.6) app to Heroku, runtime Python 3.6.1. The app runs succesfully (except the fact that tables are not created), but when trying run the makemigrations I get the following error:

```
Running python manage.py makemigrations on prochu1991... up, run.2221 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py",
 line 667, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py",
 line 611, in open_for_read_by_name
    return open(name,mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Ver
dana.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py",
 line 670, in open_for_read
    return getBytesIO(datareader(name) if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else urlopen
(name).read())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlop
en
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 549, in _open

    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call
_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1388, in unkn
own_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 137, in TTFOpenFile
    f = open_for_read(fn,'rb')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py",
 line 672, in open_for_read
    raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)
OSError: Cannot open resource "C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py"
, line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py"
, line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py"
, line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in i
mport_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/Gry/settings.py", line 19, in <module>
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Verdana', 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf', 'U
TF-8'))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self.face = TTFontFace(filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontInde
x)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 1042, in __init__
    TTFontFile.__init__(self, filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontI
ndex)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 412, in __init__
    TTFontParser.__init__(self, file, validate=validate,subfontIndex=subfontInde
x)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.readFile(file)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 239, in readFile
    self.filename, f = TTFOpenFile(f)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfont
s.py", line 147, in TTFOpenFile
    raise TTFError('Can\'t open file "%s"' % fn)
reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf"
```

settings.py

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping

#PDF Settings
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Verdana', 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
addMapping('Verdana',0,0,'Verdana') 
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+hi1^3uy-5p=h!pq9-(og2$hu$ojw(&97d%71%cnkjeky*4&)#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Gry.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Gry.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I'm using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've hardcoded the path to your ttf file to a location on your local Windows machine. Obviously that is not going to work on Heroku. You need to ensure that file is within your report and use a relative path.

Also, you cannot use sqlite on Heroku. Luckily, your DATABASES setting will be overridden because you are using dj_database_url.

Comment: But can you tell me how i have to use a relative path? And How can i not hardcode my ttf file?

Comment: In exactly the same way as you've done for your static paths. And as I say that file needs to be inside your project - how can you expect Heroku to read from your own Windows diretory?